# Регулярное выражение выбирает вместо перечисленных букв, все подряд

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Написал регулярное выражение для php  `if( preg_match("/[Кк]ра[юй]/",$name));`
Я хотел сделать так, что бы оно пропускало строки "Край", "Краю", "край" и "краю", но в результате оно почему-то пропускает все слова начинающиеся на кра или Кра, у который 4-ая буква любая. Т.е. пропускает и краб. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему последнее условие `[юй]`, работает не так, как нужно, пропуская слова не только с ю и й, но и с другими буквами?

Comment: А если так '/[Кк]{1}ра[юй]{1}/'?

Comment: Всёравно пропускает

Comment: @vlad3243, Вы не забывайте про 2 вещи:

1) фиксировать начало и конец строки

2) Конструкция [Кк] пропустит К, пропустит к и пропустит пустую строку.

Comment: @ВикторЕвлампьев, первое правильно, второе - нет.

Comment: preg_match("/[^Кк(рай|раю)]/i",$name,$matches);print_r($matches);
poprobuyte eto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы работаете с `utf8`. Для корректной работы с юникодом для регулярных выражений в PHP необходимо указывать модификатор `u` (не `U`, а `u`)

```
melkij@melkij:~$ php -r 'var_dump(preg_match("/[Кк]ра[юй]/","краб"));'
int(1)
melkij@melkij:~$ php -r 'var_dump(preg_match("/[Кк]ра[юй]/u","краб"));'
int(0)
melkij@melkij:~$ php -r 'var_dump(preg_match("/[Кк]ра[юй]/u","край"));'
int(1)
```

Без этого модификатора символьная маска рассматривает 2-байтовые коды кириллицы как два разных символа и поэтому нормально работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Верный regex, непонятно почему не работает, попробуйте так:
"#[к]ра[юй]#i"

Также дополните примерные содержания переменной $name

Comment: Ваш пропустит краЮ и краЙ, а это автору не надо, как я понял.

Comment: неправильно поняли, ему нужно чтобы не пропускал "краб" :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот если мне надо всего 4-ре варианта я бы написал скорее всего такую конструкцию

```
if( strpos($message,'Край') !== false
    || strpos($message,'край') !== false
    || strpos($message,'краю') !== false
    || strpos($message,'Краю') !== false 
  ) {
     echo 'true';
}
```